# Can you script Kodi (eg. Openelec) configuration such as upon a new deploy?

Tags: kodi, setup, openelec

I have setup Openelec on my Raspberry Pi more times than I can remember.  I'm about to do it again.  I've been spending a lot of time lately with Docker and some with Vagrant, where you script the configuration so it is easy to redeploy on different servers. I thought it would be nice if Kodi supported the same (scripted configuration).  Searches turn up very little.  Does anyone have any knowledge or experience (or ideas) of such functionality?  Perhaps a config file can be written.

Answer (score 1):

Per the advice on [Kodi's documentation for backing up](http://kodi.wiki/view/backup):

> Nearly all of Kodi's settings are stored in the userdata folder. Some
>   files, such as add-ons that are not included by default, are stored in
>   the parent folder to userdata, the Kodi folder.

*[Note: On Linux, the [userdata](http://kodi.wiki/view/Userdata_folder) folder is at ~/.kodi/userdata/]*

I haven't tested this approach, but my understanding of it (somewhat backed up by [anecdotal reports](https://problemsolvedandhow.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/copying-kodixbmc-setup-from-one-pc-to-another-pctabletphone/)) is that all you need to do is complete a fresh install and copy over the .kodi and userdata folders from your configured setup. That should bring in all your plugins.

Comment: Yes thanks goobering - that certainly is a solution that works.  Though I was hoping for some ability to script it so that deployments can be customised, such as servers that host media etc....

Comment: Potentially tricky. As many Kodi add-ons have dependencies it may be difficult to pin down which files and folders need to be in place for which add-ons to function. I think you could do some pretty tedious legwork, put together a few different complete builds and choose between those, but I don't *think* that you're going to be able to pick and choose which individual packages are included in a given installation. There is the [JSON API](http://kodi.wiki/view/JSON-RPC_API), but I can't see anything useful for you in there.

Comment: Great thanks for the feedback.  I was thinking of a Docker image that could encapsulate the dependencies and just leave the configurable bits to file and directory paths.  Generally though, I don't know much about the architecture but the problems you suggest make me think of code smells.